# CardinalityViolation: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time , in databricks --> postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting below error while loading data in postgres table :

```
INSERT INTO edh_services.ec_users
    (cdc_ID,organization_Id,user_email_ID,rec_crt_ts,rec_updt_ts) SELECT DISTINCT 
   cdc_ID, organization_Id,user_email_ID,rec_crt_ts,rec_updt_ts \
FROM 
    edh_services.ec_users_stg 
ON CONFLICT (cdc_ID) DO UPDATE SET cdc_ID = excluded.cdc_ID, 
organization_Id = excluded.organization_Id,
user_email_ID = excluded.user_email_ID,
rec_crt_ts = excluded.rec_crt_ts, 
rec_updt_ts = excluded.rec_updt_ts 
CardinalityViolation: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CardinalityViolation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1477374869543974> in <module>
     31 upsert_script = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (" +upsert_sql1[0:-1]+") SELECT DISTINCT cdc_ID, "+ tab_sql1[0:-1]+f" FROM {stg_table_name} ON CONFLICT (cdc_ID) DO UPDATE SET   "+upsert_sql2[0:-1]
     32 print(upsert_script)
---> 33 cur.execute(upsert_script)
     34 con.commit()
     35 

CardinalityViolation: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.
```

The structure of target table is :

```
create table edh_services.EC_Users
(
cdc_ID  Varchar(200),
organization_Id  BigSerial,
user_email_ID  Varchar(500),
rec_crt_ts  TIMESTAMP with Time zone,
rec_updt_ts  TIMESTAMP with Time zone,
constraint EC_Users_pk primary key (cdc_ID),
constraint EC_Users_fk foreign key (organization_Id)  references edh_services.EC_Organization (organization_Id) match simple
on update no action
on delete no action
)
```

Any suggestion how to prevent it from happening ?

Need to find any duplicate values but in which columns ?

Comment: 1) Maintain consistent naming e.g `edh_services.ec_users` vs `edh_services.EC_Users`. Since none of them are double quoted that are all going to be lower case anyway. It makes following the code easier. 2) Do not use `f` strings for dynamic SQL. 3) Run `SELECT DISTINCT  cdc_ID, organization_Id,user_email_ID,rec_crt_ts,rec_updt_ts  FROM     edh_services.ec_users_stg ` separately. The error would indicate you are returning rows that have duplicate  `cdc_ID` values.

Comment: From the docs [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT): *INSERT with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause is a “deterministic” statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error will be raised when this situation arises. Rows proposed for insertion should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by an arbiter index or constraint.*